# Are there any examples of mercenaries receiving title and land in medieval Hungary for services rendered?

Tags: middle-ages, 15th-century, hungary

I am mostly interested in examples from the 15th century. Could a former mercenary from the Black Army earn a title such as baron or count (alongside a piece of land) for serving the king (or one of his generals) well?

I checked google and wikipedia, extensively. I've seen [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_nobility#Birth_of_titled_nobility_and_the_Tripartitum) reference on Wikipedia about a title of "Perpetual Count" and another title of "Natural Baron". The issue there is that the people who received such titles seem to be of the nobility already. I was trying to find a reference for a commoner, a simple peasant, who received title and land for his services. The closest I found was [Pal Kiniszi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1l_Kinizsi) who seemed to be the son of a miller but became a general of the Black Army and received the title of count.

Comment: I think there's going to be a difference between 'could they?" (i.e., did the laws allow them to?) and "would they?" (i.e., did custom and politics allow them to?).

Comment: I checked google and wikipedia, extensively. I've seen that reference on Wikipedia about a title of "Perpetual Count" and another title of "Natural Baron". The issue there is that the people who received such titles seem to be of the nobility already. I was trying to find a reference for a commoner, a simple peasant, who received title and land for his services. The closest I found was [Pal Kiniszi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1l_Kinizsi) who seemed to be the son of a miller but became a general of the Black Army and received the title of count.

Comment: @MCW thank you for the heads up, I will add my preliminary research beforehand from now on.

Comment: [Golden Bull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Bull_of_1222#Main_points_of_the_Bull) XI and XIV seem particularly relevant to the question.

Comment: The Black Army was a big mix of people, mostly foreigners (Czecks, Polish and German). Due to the nature of mercenary, they were mostly motivated by the cash not by getting some land, and Mathias had no incentives to offer land neither. However, several of the military leaders were nobles themselves, and the mercenaries has lands, castles that exchanged with Mathias for lands in Hungary (e.g. John Jiskra). Note, that unlike in Wester Europe, the Hungarian nobility was a very populous group.